# How to fix gnuplot -e "plot 'file' u 1:($2)-1 w l" syntax?

Tags: linux, bash, plot, gnuplot

I need to plot files using gnuplot without going to gnuplot terminal. So, I am taking a quick look at the plots using the following line.

> i=2; while [ $i -le 14 ] ; do gnuplot -e "plot 'pop05'  u 1:$i w l, 'pop01' u 1:$i w l; pause 2"; ((i++)); done

However, gnuplot -e does not seem to work for the cases of

> gnuplot -e "plot 'pop01' u 1:($2)-1 w l"

ie, when I try to use an altered value in a particular column like I subtract 1 from the second column. However, `plot 'file' u 1:($2)-1 w l` works perfectly in gnuplot terminal. What should be the syntax for me to plot an altered column in the loop as well as without the loop?
I use gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$2` has a special meaning in shell in double quotes (it returns the second positional argument). Just backslash the dollar sign:

```
gnuplot -e "plot 'pop01' u 1:(\$2)-1 w l"
```

Comment: Works perfectly for the above case. But does not so for the loop (ie, $i).

Comment: @PopulationXplosive For the loop you must not do this escaping, because you actually need the replacement of `$i` with the respective value from bash.

Comment: @PopulationXplosive: No. For shell variables, use `$`, for column numbers, use `\$`.

Comment: That causes gnuplot to plot ($i)-1 th column, not the value that I get subtracting -1 from the values of ith column.

Comment: @PopulationXplosive: You need `(\$$i-1)`.